# SQL How to find progress

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT mm_strength.strengthId, mm_strength.date, sum(mm_strength_set.weight) AS total, round(sum(mm_strength_set.weight)/count(mm_strength_set.weight),1) AS average, max(mm_strength_set.weight) AS high
FROM mm_strength
INNER JOIN mm_strength_set
ON mm_strength.strengthId = mm_strength_set.strengthId
WHERE mm_strength.exerciseId = '31' AND mm_strength.customerId = '4'
GROUP BY mm_strength.strengthId 
ORDER BY mm_strength.strengthId
DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Which results in this:

```
| strengthID | date       | total | average | high | progress??
| 403        | 2013-06-08 | 32.5  | 10.8    | 12.5 | avg 10.8-prior avg 10 = 0.8
| 357        | 2013-06-04 | 30.0  | 10.0    | 10.0 | avg 10.0-prior avg 8  = 2.0
| 334        | 2013-06-02 | 24.0  | 8.0     | 8.0  | avg 8-0 (no prior)    = 8.0
```

I have tried everything, but can't seem to find a good way to create the following 6th column (progress should display increase of average from previous row):

```
| progress |
| 0.8 |
| 2.0 |
| 8.0 |
```

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: what do you mean by PROGRESS?? Its progress a table or what??

Comment: why do you have jquery tag here...i am removing it now...

Comment: How are you calculating these values?

Comment: What SQL implementation are you using? Please use a more specific tag, e.g. sql-server or mysql.

Comment: Why is this tagged php? It's just a SQL query, the language it's being called from is probably irrelevant.

Comment: I think you'll be better off keeping an aggregate table.  Calculating difference-since-last-average within the same query isn't a good idea.

Comment: Oh come on, people, it's a good question. OP is merely looking for the `lag() over ()` function, which doesn't exist in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** To be able to sort it by strengthID in descending order you just have to use an outer seelect

```sql
SELECT t.*
 FROM
(
  SELECT strengthID, date, total, high,
          average - @prev_avg progress, 
          @prev_avg := average average           
    FROM
  (
    SELECT s.strengthId, 
           s.date, 
           SUM(ss.weight) total, 
           ROUND(SUM(ss.weight)/COUNT(ss.weight),1) average, 
           MAX(ss.weight) high
      FROM mm_strength s JOIN mm_strength_set ss
        ON s.strengthId = ss.strengthId
     WHERE s.exerciseId = '31' AND s.customerId = '4'
     GROUP BY mm_strength.strengthId 
     ORDER BY mm_strength.strengthId
     LIMIT 5 
  ) q, (SELECT @prev_avg := 0) n
) t
ORDER BY strengthID DESC
```

Sample output:

```
| STRENGTHID |                        DATE | TOTAL | HIGH | PROGRESS | AVERAGE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        403 | June, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  32.5 | 12.5 |      0.8 |    10.8 |
|        357 | June, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    30 |   10 |        2 |      10 |
|        334 | June, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    24 |    8 |        8 |       8 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc3b4/7)** demo.

Comment: This works almost perfect, but I need it to be ordered by strengthId descending. If I change it the progress returns wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, works excellent! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no `lag() over ()` in MySQL, but you can work around this with variables and subqueries:

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/04/12/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=2